# How to get face data from uv position in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the face data. Either the index for `mesh.vertices[]` from which I can get the vertices of a triangle with index, index + 1, and index + 2, or any other data that would be unique to any given face would do. But, I'm trying to get the face data from uv data.

I have a square mesh of triangles, 100 by 100 vertices, which has uv coordinates generated automatically from the x and y position of the verticies divided by the "resolution" of 100x100 where x and y are values from 0 to resolution.x and from 0 to resolution.y respectively. I looked everywhere for somebody else who tried to get face data from uv data but found nothing.

I've seen a lot of questions on this site and other places asking for the opposite of uv position from face data, but unfortunately their conversions do not work the other way.

With this data I could draw each triangle with the color of the uv coordinate of its center with a shader, then use another shader to sample that as with screen coordinates to get triangulate pixels, which is my eventual goal. Feel free to recommend another approach to this if you think of something off the top of your head.

Here is the full code  made mostly from [this](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/) tutorial  for the mesh grid generation if that helps.

```
public Mesh GenerateGrid(Vector2Int _resolution, float _size = 1)
    {
        Vector2 scale = new Vector2(_size/ _resolution.x, _size / _resolution.y);

        //stolen code
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(_resolution.x + 1) * (_resolution.y + 1)];
        
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[(_resolution.x + 1) * (_resolution.y + 1)];

        //loop through each position
        for (int i = 0, y = 0; y <= _resolution.y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= _resolution.x; x++, i++) {
                //scale and position the verticies around 0,0
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y) * scale - new Vector2(_size, _size)/2;
                //auto uv generation
                uvs[i] = new Vector2(x, y) / _resolution;
            }
        }

        //this is the part i really needed the tutorial for
        int[] triangles = new int[_resolution.x * _resolution.y * 6];
        for (int ti = 0, vi = 0, y = 0; y < _resolution.y; y++, vi++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < _resolution.x; x++, ti += 6, vi++) {
                triangles[ti] = vi;
                triangles[ti + 3] = triangles[ti + 2] = vi + 1;
                triangles[ti + 4] = triangles[ti + 1] = vi + _resolution.x + 1;
                triangles[ti + 5] = vi + _resolution.x + 2;
            }
        }

        //commit the mesh and return
        Mesh m = new Mesh();
        m.vertices = vertices;
        m.uv = uvs;
        m.triangles = triangles;

        return m;
```

And here is the code for calculating face centers and uv centers
(in Start())

```
//generate uv map where each triangle is the uv coordinate of its center

        //get face centers, only has to be a vector2 because i wont be using the depth for this
        Vector2[] centers = new Vector2[mesh.triangles.Length / 3];
        Vector2[] centersUV = new Vector2[centers.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.triangles.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            //just get the average positions for the vertices of each face
            int j = mesh.triangles[i * 3];
            Vector3 sum = mesh.vertices[j];
            Vector2 sumUV = mesh.uv[j];

            j = mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 1];
            sum += mesh.vertices[j];
            sumUV += mesh.uv[j];

            j = mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 2];
            sum += mesh.vertices[j];
            sumUV += mesh.uv[j];

            centers[i] = sum / 3;
            centersUV[i] = sum / 3;
        }
```

I don't think that there is anything wrong with the code but they're mostly here in case that they're the key to figuring this whole thing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a different approach to my general goal but this specific question will remain open.

I made this shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Test"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Distortion ("Distortion Texture", 2D) = "black" {}
        _Dscale ("Distortion scale", Range (0, 1)) = 0.0
        _Size ("Size", Range(0.001,1)) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            float4 fraction (float4 vec, float size)
            {
                return float4(vec.x % size, vec.y % size, vec.z % size, vec.w % size);
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _Distortion;
            float _Dscale;
            float _Size;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {

                //distort uv
                float2 d = i.uv + (tex2D(_Distortion, i.uv) * _Dscale).xy;

                //separate screen into squares
                float2 p = fraction(float4(d, 1, 1), _Size).xy;
                
                //adjust squares for position
                float2 q = d - p;

                //calculate whether triangle will be in the up or down state with a linear equation
                float b = p.x > p.y;

                //use up down state to choose between colors
                fixed4 col;
                float2 tris = fixed4(0.666, 0.333, 0, 1) * b + fixed4(0.333, 0.666, 0, 1) * (1 - b);

                float2 final = q + tris * _Size;

                //col = fixed4(final, 1, 1);
                col = tex2D(_MainTex, final);     

                //col /= _Size;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

This is a camera effect shader that uses the modulo operator to split the screen into squares and then splits those squares into triangles with essentially a linear y = ax + b. The fixed4s after the declaration of color are the local centers of each of those triangles, which are then adjusted to the full screen uv space. The triangles centers are read from instead of the screen uv and a triangular pixel effect is created. You can also add a distortion texture to soften the edges so it looks a little less icky.

I'm going to look into raycasting for a solution to my specific question, since it is unlikely a solution will be needed that can be used to draw full screen textures.